# snapshot containing indexes, while try to restore getting partition mismatch error in docker cassandra

Tags: docker, cassandra, restore, cassandra-4.0

Currently I took snapshot using `nodetool snapshot` command and when I try to restore the data into cassandra docker container by stopping it and executing `nodetool repair` I am getting following error message for some tables.

```
 partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.LocalPartitioner does not 
 match system partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner. 
 Note that the default partitioner starting with Cassandra 1.2 is Murmur3Partitioner, 
 so you will need to edit that to match your old partitioner if upgrading.
```

Version I am using is `docker cassandra: 4.0.1` .Now I am looking for help regarding this error.

more detailed versions:

```
INFO  [main] 2022-07-07 11:54:10,806 StorageService.java:734 - Cassandra version: 4.0.1
INFO  [main] 2022-07-07 11:54:10,806 StorageService.java:735 - CQL version: 3.4.5
INFO  [main] 2022-07-07 11:54:10,806 StorageService.java:736 - Native protocol supported versions: 3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5, 6/v6-beta (default: 5/v5)
```

A bit more context is that I was trying to restore the tables containing indexs , which are also backed up into hidden directory as an sstable format.

So when I stopped the container and copied containing index and table files to the exact same table I created, then I run the `nodetool refresh` command it stopped working and thrown the above error.

commands I executed:

```
docker stop cassandra
docker cp backup_table cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra/data/{keyspace_name}/{table_name}
docker start cassandra
docker exec cassandra nodetool refresh ks ts
```

similar issue I saw: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9654
https://lists.apache.org/thread/dnpbytgl59h3q0x0pgw8yp3thlmzm3yr

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a bit more info for us to be able to help you. In particular, the following would be a good start:

- a sample table schema
- steps to replicate the issue

It isn't possible to run `nodetool` commands if the Cassandra instance is stopped like you state here:

> ... when I try to restore the data into cassandra docker container by stopping it and executing `nodetool repair` ...

and you don't perform a restore running the command which is why it is important that you provide details of how to replicate the problem. Cheers!

Comment: I will add the example, just give me a day.